# How to get actual controls from literal control?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a user control in which I have added one GridView control. In that I have added some controls dynamically. When I'm trying to get a particular control from my GridView from user control, I am getting a Literal control instead of an actual control.

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls){
  if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(LookupControl))  {
    //do action
  }
}
```

Comment: are you want to access the controls from inside gridview?

Comment: @Talhs: yes,I want the controls in gridview

Answer (score 0):

Just Cast it to the required type:

```
LookUpControl myCtrl = (LookUpControl)ctrl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply .But I am getting following error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'Accenture.CSTPrague.WebControls.LookupControl'.

Comment: That means your control is not inherited from the Class control or any of its subclasses. Try inheriting from control